# How to remove an item from listbox in gwt.?

Tags: java, gwt, listbox

I am working with listBox implementation in GWT but stuck while removing an item from that listBox and I have only text that is to be removed from listBox. How can I achieve this in GWT.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gwt listbox offers you the method removeItem(int index). So with a simple loop you can remove your item:

**Edit**: Like mentioned in the comment from Baz, you should reverse the loop. Otherwise it won't work correcly in all cases. If there are duplicates in the list or you add another equals into the loop, it will lead to Bugs.

```
            ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
            //add some entries to the listbox
            int itemCount = listbox.getItemCount();

            for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                if ("YOURTEXT".equals(listbox.getItemText(i))) {
                    statusListBox.removeItem(i);
                }
            }
```

If you also just want to remove only one item, you can add a `break` after the `removeItem`.

Comment: You should store the item count in a variable and loop down instead of up, because you're removing items while looping.